# Delete argument in ifelse

Tags: if-statement, ggplot2

I've been trying to graph only for the past few hours. I only want to graph the TRUE arguments of this ifelse statement

```
which(RawGame1$event_desc == "Off Rebound")
reb <- ifelse(RawGame1$event_desc_id == "O",1,"")
```

Right now whenever I try to plot with ggplot, I get a bar graph where 13/22 bars are the 3rd argument(pointless data) that skews the scales and dimensions horribly. How do i delete them? Am i trying to graph it wrong?

```
ggplot(RawGame1[,], aes(x = pid.first.char, fill = reb)) +
geom_bar() +
ggtitle("Off Reb by Player") +
xlab("Player") +
ylab("Total Rebounds")
```

There has to be a simpler way i don't know about!?!? New to R and appreciate any help. Be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to answer if you provided a sample of your data (at least what `head(RawGame1)` prints out), also what the plot looks like now and what's the goal.

But I see that you have brackets without any filtering condition in `RawGame1[,]` - if you intended to select only `event_desc_id=="0"` there, just write `RawGame1[RawGame1$event_desc_id==0,]`.